# Updating thousands of react children via parent websocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

Scenario context:
App displays "watchlists" of various stock ticker prices in a list. The user can add however many "watchlists" as he/she pleases. Each watchlist contains stock items, which display last price etc...

Current Hierarchy:

- Container (Grandparent) connects to stock data websocket, houses watchlists, passes websocket message down via props

  - Watchlist (Parent) houses stock items, passes websocket data to child via props

    - Stock item (Child) renders stock prices from websocket data prop

Attempted designs:
I have tried a couple designs, they all function but they are not performant.

1. Pass websocket data from Grandparent -> parent -> child via props (Slow, re-renders all watchlists)
2. Each child listens on websocket to render stock price (Very slow, a single websocket cannot listen to hundreds or thousands of watchlists)

Question:
**What is an efficient and performant component design for reading a single data source (Grandparent's websocket data in my case) in hundreds or thousands of react children?**
[image: How it looks on the UI for reference]

Comment: This is a good use case for a specialized state management system like [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/). Each component can subscribe to only the bits of state it needs (and re-render accordingly).

Comment: @jsejcksn Thanks for the suggestion I will check that out. I have also never used Redux, but I have heard it may be another option for this use case.